# Why can't get sound with HTML audio tag with autoplay attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to make a  creat html page  for a trainer. So I wanted to have start page sound audio which automatically plays. But, when I open the start page, this audio file doesn't autoplay. I tested it with a chrome browser

This is my code:

```html
<audio id="myautoload" autoplay>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script> document.getElementById('myautoload').play(); </script>
```

I used the other way, it also does not autoplay

```html
var myadido = document.getElementById("myautoload");
  myadido.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
     {
      setTimeout(function() {
      myadido.play();

      },500);

  });
```

I've tried your solution, but the audio still won't play.

I hope everyone helps me, thank you so much

Comment: Why snippet on your question ?

Comment: audio should have id="myaudio"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome my snippet is running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio autoplay id="myautoload">
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myadido = document.getElementById("myautoload");

    setTimeout(function() {
    myadido.play();

    },500);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I received the message "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException" on the chrome browser. At ( myadido.play(); )

Comment: Thank you, I have successfully tested on IE, An error occurred due to chrome browser on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Audio tag needs `id="myaudio"` like so:

```
<audio id="myaudio" autoplay>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script> document.getElementById('myaudio').play(); </script>
```

The script you have at the bottom looks for a tag with an id `'myaudio'` and it calls `play()` on it to play the audio clip.

Tested in chrome 70.0.3538

### Edit

The error you've come across is basically because the promise returned from calling the play method was not being caught (see code below for handling the promise).

However, further to this there are  [changes in Chrome's autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) coming this month which will affect the ability to autoplay on Chrome. In short, you'll need permissions if you want to autoplay audio on a webpage, otherwise you'll need to wait for user interaction before you can play the audio.

Below is an example that will check if you can auto play (the AudioContext's state will transition immediately to 'running') otherwise it will start playing after user interaction (the user presses the button).

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head></head>
<body>
  <button> start</button>
  <audio id="myaudio" autoplay>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
  </audio>
  <script>

    var context;
    window.onload = function() {
     context = new AudioContext();
      context.onstatechange = function() {
        //if you have permissions, the audioContext will transition to 'running' immediately
        if(context.state == 'running') {
          play();
        }
      }
    };

    function play() {
        //ensure the promise is handled here
        var promise = document.getElementById('myaudio').play();
        if (promise !== undefined) {
          promise.then(_ => {
            console.log("playing");
          }).catch(error => {
            // Autoplay was prevented.
          });
        }
    }

    //play after the user interacts with the page
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      context.resume().then(function() {
        play();
      });
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have programmed the code correctly, but currently it is not autoplay

Comment: works for me with a local file. if you open the inspector in chrome (OSX: Command+Option+i or windows: Ctrl+Shift+i on Windows) do you see any errors?

Comment: I checked that there was an error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException. In line of code:  myadido.play();

Comment: I need autoplay when loading page. I do not need to use the button function. Using the button play, it's simple

Comment: Did you read the explanation or visit the link? For Chrome, many cases actually require user interaction. The edit details why it fails on Chrome and how to make it work in future versions of Chrome (M71). For people searching for a cross-browser solution, a simple implementation won't be sufficient.