# How do I make a video/audio file autoplay consistently?

Tags: html, audio

I want to make audio and video files autoplay on my website at http://34.69.99.240/, but they play sometimes, and then other times they don't.

I've tried adding the autoplay attribute to the audio but like I said it only works some of the time, the rest it just doesn't play.

```
<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I would think that autoplay makes the file automatically play, but so far it only plays if the file was downloaded fast enough. Is it possible to make it play consistently, every single time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome Maybe?

Comment: Hopefully it helps!!

Comment: It still doesn't work though :( at least i can just not show it now

Comment: I tried it, it still doesn't work on the first few visits but then it works consistently after that. Sadly, i need it on first try.

Comment: This one looks promising, by delaying the start of auto play it might assist with spoofing Google's new policy where it blocks auto play? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863789/why-cant-get-sound-with-html-audio-tag-with-autoplay-attribute